# Как пользоваться yii rights?

Tags: yii

Может кто-нибудь доступно объяснить? Нужно иметь роли: юзер, админ, объект, гость. Как их добавить и проверять в коде?

П.С. Использую (пробую) в связке с расширением yii-user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну на самом деле [вот ссылка](http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3056)
нужно ведь не просто yii-user а еще и yii-right и они должны вместе работать.
Там и документация есть, правда на инглише но думаю будет понятно.

Вот ссылки [Yii-User](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user/) [Yii-Rights](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rights/) 
А для полного счастья, можно и своё написать, труда особого нет, 3 таблицы и все.

Comment: @Shrek, установить труда не составило вроде. Особенно, когда нашел готовое решение: http://code.google.com/p/yii-web-start/downloads/list

Я не понимаю как в rights назначить юзеру одни action контроллера, другим другие. Там какие-то Права, Роли, Разрешение, Задачи, Операции. Можете привести пример, как например Guest запретить доступ к скажем site/contact ?

Comment: http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/topics.auth

Параграф "фильтр контроля доступа"

Answer (score 1):

На [yiiframework.ru](http://yiiframework.ru/) есть [рецепт](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/cookbook/ru/access.rbac.file) настройки доступа на основе ролей.

После этого доступ к экшенам настраивается через `accessRules()`:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        /*...*/
        array('allow',
            'actions'=>array(/*...*/),
            'roles'=>array('moder'),
        ),
        /*...*/
    );
}
```

Также в коде можно использовать:

```
Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('moder')
```

Comment: Мне нужно именно в Rights

Answer (score 0):

а вам точно yii user нужен? 
есть же RBAC и ваши задачи он решает полностью. 
установить можно за пять минут. 
вот прекрасное пособие. самому помогло в свое время
http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2015/03/yii-rbac.html